Where are the pure colors on CIE diagram?
Where are the pure colors on CIE diagram?
I think that they are only along the curved edge.
Are the colors in the 'straight line of purples' also considered as pure colors?
Are pure colors only along the curved edge or along the edges?
Screenshot for reference


the question in the link is "where is blue" not what you state.

@JEB Yes, I saw that the question has changed, earlier it was different. Anyways, I have changed my question now to make it relevant.

This question isn't really about physics. Maybe try Graphic Design SE.

I suppose the lesson should have given you a definition of a pure color. And this definition will depend on the field of study. For a physicist a pure color will be a spectral color. For a graphics designer it may well be a color with highest possible saturation for its hue. These sets of colors overlap but are not the same.

If by "pure colour" you mean a spectral colour (i.e. a colour that corresponds to the spectral line of monochromatic light with a given wavelength) then these colours lie along the arch-shaped curved edge of the CIE diagram. The spectral colours are arranged in order of increasing wavelength, from violet at the bottom left of the arch through green at the top of the arch to red at the bottom right.
The colours along the bottom edge of the diagram are not spectral colours, they are mixtures of violet and red in different proportions - see the Wikipedia article on line of purples.

Here's the diagram:

In physics, I would take the meaning of "pure color" to be "eigenstate of the:
$$ i\frac{\partial}{\partial t} $$
operator with eigenvalue:
$$ \lambda_f = 2\pi f $$
(sorry but lambda is the trad name for eigenvalues), which can be converted into a wavelength:
$$ \lambda(f) = \frac c f $$
which, after division by $1\,$nm, is of course labeled in blue along the curved boundary. I would exclude the purple straight edge.
Meanwhile, for normies, A.I. says:
A pure color is the color with the greatest saturation in each hue.
which is what it is.

You did not answered the question

@AnshulGupta you didn't define "pure color".

What is the $t$ with respect to which your operator is differentiating?

@Ruslan a plane wave of pure color: $A(x, t) =A e^{i(kx-\omega t)}$ with $\omega = ck$.
